# Using multi-processing and multi-threading at the same sime

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

I need to use multiprocessing and multi threading at the same time. But when I search on the internet every source compare multiprocessing and multithreading. And it's little confusing because they are very close terms. Here what is the expected threads:
[image: thread scheme 1]

[image: thread scheme 2]

Is there any idea or resource about that? How can I use multithreading and multiprocessing at the same time?

Comment: The main difference between both approaches is that threads share the memory space, whereas processes don't. You should refer to your operating system manuals, or check `boost::interprocess` and `boost::thread`.

Comment: thank you @JuanR . I'm just confused about the expected job basically they are doing the same job and multithread is more beneficial but they want both. Thank you anyway,

Comment: Sometimes you need the extra separation provided by processes and processes run on other hardware. In multithreading, one thread goes sufficiently nuts and you lose everything.  You have to go out of your way to corrupt one process from another process. And of course that wall inserts some extra challenges.